# Guidelines causing problem while doing alignment in Adobe Illustrator CS4

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment, cs4, guides

I have an artwork and inside that artwork there are several objects and several guidelines applied. Now when I try to align that artwork at the edge of the main Artboard using alignment tools, the artwork is placed outside the artboard because of inner guidelines.

So my question is that if there is any option by which I can exclude guidelines from consideration while doing alignment.

Comment: Hi arvind, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1):

Try -
hide the guidelines 'View-guides-hide guides' or keyboard shortcut- (Ctrl+; for windows/ cmmd +; for mac) also turn off smart guides from view menu or use shortcut (ctrl+ u for windows/cmd+u for mac). Or use alignment - To artboard.
I think this will help.
[image]

Comment: Hi Ash De, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer! If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!